# I Made Wordpress Multisite. And Now Everything Doesn't Display Properly

Tags: apache

I installed Ubuntu 10.4 then I installed Bitnami LAMP stack then I installed bitnami wordpress module then I tried to make the site into a multisite by following these instructions:

http://wiki.bitnami.org/Applications/BitNami_WordPress_Multisite#How_to_add_several_WordPress_Multisite_blogs_with_different_domains.3f

AND

http://wiki.bitnami.org/Applications/BitNami_WordPress_Multisite

I can elaborate if needed: I enabled multisite in my `wp-config.php` file. Then I created a network using the wordpress dashboard. I was given two blocks of text to copy and paste 1 block into my wp-config.php file and one into my `.htaccess` file. I did that and now I get this:

When I go to my `mywebsite.com` I get this (this was there before I switched to multisite):

[image: before switch]

If I go to `mywebsite.com/wordpress` I get this (this used to be a functioning wordpress theme):

[image: /wordpress]

If I click on "My Blog" it redirects to 1mywebsite.com (where the "1" came from I have no idea)

If I try to login by going to `mywebsite.com/wordpress/wp-login` I get this:

[image: wp-login]

and if I enter my user and password it redirects me to mywebsite.com/wp-login.php and gives me "Not Found" The requested URL `/wp-login.php` was not found on this server.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampstack-5.3.16-0/apps/wordpress
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with bitnami so I don't know how it changes the apache configuration but I would say the problem is the domain mapping.

mywebsite.com maps to lets say /var/www/mywebsite 
but your wordpress is installed in /var/www/mywebsite/wordpress 
so the  url to it isn't mywebsite.com but mywebsite.com/wordpress and when you login it redirects you to mywebsite.com/wp-login beacuse in the dashboard you set the site address as mywebsite.com and not mywebsite.com/wordpress.

I would say you have two options:

You can change the site address that you entered in dashboard throuhg mysql in table wp-options, the siteurl value (you can do that thorugh phpMyAdmin if it is installed on the machine)

or

Change the document root for mywebiste.com in you Virtual host to the directory where wordpress is installed (you just add /wordpress to the end) ([VirtualHost examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) if you're begginer with them)

Comment: My wordpress folder is located in /opt/lampstack-5.3.16-0/apps/wordpress... I am going to try to follow this guide to fix it: http://www.lanexa.net/2011/08/how-to-change-the-wordpress-site-url-using-mysql-command-line/

Comment: Yes that changes the siteurl value in wp-options table

Comment: Well, I tried to follow those instructions from that website and it's telling me that 'mysql' is not installed. But when I run the command ctlscript.sh restart mysql, it does just that, it stops mysql, then starts it. So I'm pretty sure I have mysql installed. Furthermore, I have tried to do this through the wp-config.php file by changing define('WP_SITEURL','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/wordpress'); and define('WP_HOME','http://.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/wordpress'); to: define('WP_SITEURL','http://mywebsite.com'); and define('WP_HOME','http://mywebsite.com'); to no avail

Comment: I also tried to set define('WP_HOME','http://mywebsite.com/wordpress'); and define('WP_SITEURL','http://mywebsite.com/wordpress'); and that didn't work either. So basically, right now I am stuck at mysql not being recognized

Comment: wp-login.php i think redirects to siteurl values from mysql not the wp-config.php but I'm not sure about that. I suggest you put wp-config.php back to original values and try to change the virtual host for mywebsite.com

Comment: I already put them back to the original which is: define('WP_SITEURL','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/wordpress'); and define('WP_HOME','http://.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/wordpress');............... I will edit my post within 30 seconds to put up what I think should be in the vhosts file, can you check if it looks right?

Comment: I just tried what I put up in my post, and I restarted apache, and it didn't do anything.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-loginphp-redirects-to-page-not-found check this, this is I think the same problem as yours, check the two links in last post, it states that for multisite installations you have to make changes in the database itself

Comment: what was the original value of document root, it went to bitnami installation I would say according your first picture. I don't know how bitnami affects all of this, what is the bitnami installation folder